# template needs typename declared with each class member functions returns yet not able to link when compile?

Tags: c++

I have a class with template and class member with return type of the template class.

```
// in header
namespace A
{
 template<class Data>
 class Tree
 {
     enum class InsertionStatus
     {
        INSERT_LEFT,
        INSERT_RIGHT,
        NO_INSERTION,
        INSERTION_COMPLETE
     };
     struct Node 
     {
        Data data;
        Node *left, *right, *previous;
     };

     InsertionStatus insertNode(Node* newNode, std::function<InsertionStatus(Data&, Data&)> insertion_method = NULL);
  
 }
}
```

```
// in another cpp
using namespace A;
template<class Data>
typename Tree<Data>::InsertionStatus Tree<Data>::insertNode(Node* newNode, std::function<InsertionStatus(Data&, Data&)> insertion_method)
{
    if (HasNoRoot())
    {
        return InsertionStatus::INSERTION_COMPLETE;
    }
    return InsertionStatus::NO_INSERTION;
}
```

The compiler returns outer link not interpretable.

Comment: The template method needs to be instantiated. One (the simplest) methods is to move the definition of the method to the header.

Comment: @DmitryKuzminov thank you for the reply, why does it need to be instantiated in the class definition? could you explain or give a example?

Comment: [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each template function is a unique function from the point of view of the linker.

Consider the module where the function is being called. Whenever you call the function, the compiler generates the call to the `Tree<Data>::insertNode` function where `Data` is a concrete type known in the module. If you define the template function in the header, the compiler knows everythin it needs to generate the body of the function instantiated with the concrete class. Then the linker would find this code in the module and link.

If you don't define the template functon in the header, and the compiler doesn't see the code the defines the template function, it cannot generate the assembler code for it.

Now consider another module where you define the template function. It knows how to generate the assembler code for any type... but it doesn't know which types it should generate this function for.

There are multiple solutions how to solve the issue. First: define the template function body in the header where the template class is being defined. In this case the compiler sees all the code it needs to define the assembler code. Another solution: explicitly instantiate the class in the module where the function is defined for each type you plan to use.